# Node root/Admin errors on FRESH windows 10 install

Tags: node.js, npm

This is literally killing me, iv'e spent probably 5days of work-time trying to fix this problem and made no progress.

This is where i'm at.
After a fresh windows 10 install, installing node, git, intellij-webstorm, java and jdk.
Node will work for 1-2 days then a single npm install command will fail with the following error:
[image: node js error]
(url https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9G0m.png)
first, a npm install command will fail with that delete error.
then all subsequent npm install commands will fail with root/Administrator error.

- Iv'e done substantial googling, can't npm cache clean --force it fails with root/Admin error
- Running cmd as admin makes no difference.
- Can't delete cache gives me invalid windows permission error.
- can't "takeown /f npm-cache /r" windows command (fails with errors on some files)
- even if i delete npm-cache using a file unlocking software, future npm commands still fail.
- Completely uninstalling npm including deleteing all AppData files, still results in same problem INSTANTLY after re-installing.
- reinstalling a slightly older version has still resulted in the same problem.

Desperate at this point as to what the problem could be.

Only thing i haven't tried is firewall disable because its a work computer this isn't possible.

INTERESTING THINGS TO NOTE:
When it fails on a fresh install for the first time, running cmd as admin WILL make npm install work, but after you restart this will no longer work in admin or in regular cmd

Comment: why are you running with `--production` flag?  try simply `npm install -g windows-build-tools`.  You may also need to do `npm cache clean`.

Comment: npm cache clean --force gives me same error.
the install command doesn't matter, its failed on different install commands multiple times each time the result has been unfixable, have to re-install windows to get it to work for 1-2 days.